# How to enable Qt Creator 3.2.2 to use GDB?

Tags: qt-creator, gdb

After installing Qt Creator 3.2.2 from source I tried to run my project with Qt Creator's debugger frontend, but instead of starting to debug I got an error from Qt Creator:

> The selected build of GDB does not support Python scripting. It cannot be used in Qt Creator.

Does it mean that I have to build GDB from source, selecting python support, to be able to use Qt Creator in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [this blogpost](http://qtway.blogspot.ru/2014/06/the-selected-build-of-gdb-does-not.html), default<sup>1</sup> install of GDB in Ubuntu appears to be `gdb-minimal`. To get a version of GDB usable with Qt Creator, you can just do

```
sudo apt-get install gdb
```

which will remove `gdb-minimal`, install `gdb` and additionally install `libc6-dbg`. After this you'll be able to debug your project using QtCreator without getting such errors.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>I'm not sure in what sense it is the default, maybe it's installed with `build-essential`, or something else...</sub>